# Check when text is at specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have text inside a div that scrolls down using the **jquery marquee** plugin. It sort of acts as an introduction to a project I'm working on. I want to reveal that project to the user as soon as the text in the div is completely done scrolling.

How can I know when the text is completely gone from the screen? How do I get its position?

PS: Before you think you know how it should work. Can you try it out yourself using my code in the snippet?

```js
/*INTRO*/
    $('#intro').marquee({
        duration: 15000,
        gap: 5,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: 'down',
        pauseOnHover: true,
        duplicated: false
    });
```

```css
#intro{
 font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
 position: absolute; 
 opacity: 0.5;
 font-size: 140%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 200%;
 top: -20%;
    left: 7%;
 padding-left:15%;
 padding-right:15%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.9/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>
  <div id="intro"><p><b><i>THIS IS MY SCROLLING INTRO THAT'S SUPPOSED TO SHOW THE NEXT THING ONLY WHEN THE TEXT IS COMPLETELY DONE SCROLLING</i></p></div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pum96ek/) of it as well.

Comment: FYI, you're not closing your `<b>` tag

Comment: This marquee happens with the time duration 15000, once this millisec you can hide the intro div and show your project content container div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `finished` event on your `$('#intro')`, like so

```
$('#intro').on('finished', function () {
    alert('Text done scrolling');
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/4pum96ek/1/)

UPDATE:

Hey also if you want to show something right after you can `destroy` the marquee in order to stop it from continuous rotation and therefore memory consumption on the client side.

So i've updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/4pum96ek/2/) to show how that could work, but the changes are minor:

HTMl:

```
  <div id="intro"><p><b><i>THIS IS MY SCROLLING INTRO THAT'S SUPPOSED TO SHOW THE NEXT THING ONLY WHEN THE TEXT IS COMPLETELY DONE SCROLLING</i></b></p></div>

  <div id="project">
    <h1>
      Project here
    </h1>
  </div>
```

Additional CSS:

```
#project {
  display: none;
}

#project.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Finally the JS:

```
/*INTRO*/
    $('#intro')
    .bind('finished', function(){
                console.log('has finished');
                //Change text to something else after first loop finishes
        $(this).marquee('destroy'); // I thought it would remove the element, but it just stop the marquee
        $(this).hide(); // So perhaps hide you would like to hide it.
        //Show project
        $('#project').addClass('active');
    })
    .marquee({
        duration: 15000,
        gap: 5,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: 'down',
        pauseOnHover: true,
        duplicated: false
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I can definitely use this to do away with too much memory consumption.